# Linux and Windows machine ncat issues

Tags: linux, windows

How can I make this transfer correctly? Using `ncat` between linux and windows. Trying to transfer file with text. Linux DOES receive file but file is blank. Need file to have message that was written.

Command:

```
ncat -l > Hello.txt
```

Error Message:

```
ncat bind to :::31337 already in use. QUITTING.
```

Still very new to `ncat`

nvm Im an idiot please ignore

Comment: "_Linux DOES receive file_" no it doesn't; the listening port is already in use. But by that stage the shell has already created your output file for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running WSL? You can't use the same port on the same machine for sending and receiving. In this instance `netcat` can't work.

If you're not using WSL then you already have a process using the default 31337 port. Either end that older process or use a different port for your transfer.

Comment: Thank you very much I think I found a way to have be transferred on another port

Comment: I'm curious. Are you using WSL or two different machines?

Comment: Im using a VM (kali linux) and theres a rdesktop that I use for a windows machine and I am using ncat to transfer files between the two machines. They can connect. I was able to preform both connections but I haven't found away to download/upload a file. Every time I do its transfers the file but the content of the file isn't there.

Comment: If the content isn't there then by definition it hasn't transfered the file. I suggest you ask a new question: explain the situation (Windows, with Kali in a VM) and the problem you need to solve, along with both parts of the netcat thing you're trying to use. You might want to reference [your question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565988/100397) in your new question.